# creating a simple processing p5.js library

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I was trying to create a simple library and ran into problems. This is my html file:

```
`
<html>
    <script src = 'p5.min.js'></script>
    <script src = 'mosaic.js'></script>
    <script src = 'sketch.js'></script>
    <body>
        <script>setMosaic(true)</script>
    </body>
</html>
`
```

mosaic.js is the library I am creating.

The content of mosaic.js is :

```
`
p5.prototype._isMosaic = false;
p5.prototype.setMosaic = function(status){
    this._isMosaic = status;
    console.log('set worked');
  };
`
```

If I call setMosaic from inside the  as shown in the html file, it gives me a function not defined error. But I can call setMosaic() successfully from inside setup() or draw() of sketch.js. Calling setMosaic from outside the sketch works when I define setMosaic in /src/environment/environment.js and build p5.js again.

Is there a way to call setMosaic from outside the sketch?

EDIT (in response to the comment):

1) I'm trying to build a framework that can scale the sketch into multiple screens. So the person who writes the sketch has to do it the normal way, but my tool will be calling some functions that communicates with a server e.t.c. So I need to call these functions outside the sketch, but they should be bound to the p5 object (namespace) because the functions I write in turn will have to call some functions internal to p5js. This is [my project](https://github.com/lonesword/openmosaic).

2) Value is going to be affected per sketch.

Comment: Two questions: 1) what do you mean by "outside the sketch" (since p5 is about building individual sketches, it doesn't really have meaningful behaviour outside of those) and 2) is this value supposed to be manipulable "per sketch" or is it supposed to be a superglobal that you set on P5, and then every sketch that relies on it is affected?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've edited the question to include the details you mentioned as well. Also, I think the problem has something to do with the namespace. I can call setMosaic from INSIDE setup() in sketch, but not from a <script> tag in the html page. when I try calling p5.setMosaic(), it says p5 is not defined. Can be a javascript nuance I don't know about. Thanks

Comment: Additional request: do you have an example jsbin or something so we can try to update the code for you?

Comment: I could not find a service that lets me add multiple js files. So I've put together a .zip here:
http://d.pr/f/10nui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by calling setMosaic as p5.prototype.setMosaic().
It was answered [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9855/creating-a-simple-library#latest).